# how do i get the sentence in a document containing a particular word using python?

Tags: python

From an entire text, I want to extract the whole sentence in which a given word appears. For example:

```
text = "The cat ran. I am Sam. Whoop dee doo."
output = get_sentence("am")
```

Should yield --> `"I am Sam."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `nltk` library to tokenize the sentence

```
nltk.download("punkt")
text = "Hello, I am Taksh. Nice to meet you Mr. Panchal. 
                    You scored 82.5 % in test"
nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize(text)
>> ['Hello, I am Taksh.',
    'Nice to meet you Mr. Panchal.',
    'You scored 82.5 % in test']
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the string into sentences then search each for the phrase

```py
text = text.split('. ')
for s in text:
    if searchWord in s:
        return s + "."
    return "Search word not found"
```

Comment: Are you sure that `text.split('. ')` is good for splitting text into sentences?

Comment: sentences can end like this! can't they?

Comment: This works for OP's provided input. A greater range of punctuation would require Regex

Comment: @Chris_Rands what about such sentence: "Hello, Mr. Guido"?

Comment: @JammyDodger this topic has been discussed a lot. It's around impossible to build a good combination of regex to handle _all_ possible cases. It's always a good idea to build a system with several layers, including nltk of course.

Answer (score 0):

```
text = "The cat ran. I am Sam. Whoop dee doo."
text =  text.split('.')
data = input("Enter the String want to search")
for i in text:
   if data in i:
      print(i )
   else:
      print("search word is not present")
```

Comment: Please explain how your code works so OP can understand exactly what you did